# google-app-engine-django loading fixtures

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, fixtures, django-fixtures

I'm having troubles loading fixtures on GAE with google-app-engine-django. I receive an error that says "DeserializationError: Invalid model identifier: 'fcl.User'"

> > > ./manage.py loaddata users

I'm trying to load a fixture that has the following data:

```
- model: fcl.User
  fields:
    firstname: test
    lastname: testerson
    email: test@example.com
    user_id: '981167207188616462253'
    status: active
    usertype: player
    creationtime: '2010-08-29 00:00:00'
```

do I need to do any other qualifying of my model name? The fixture lives at fcl/fixtures/users.yaml and model lives in at 'fcl/models.py'.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the issue was caused because I wasn't declaring my model correctly in models.py

When using google-app-engine-django, each model should be a subclass of:

```
appengine_django.db.BaseModel
```

after fixing this, it works. I also needed to put a valid pk: value in my fixture.